# PlatformException(sign_in_failed, Status{statusCode=CANCELED, resolution=null}, null) error in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, google-oauth

I used [google_sign_in 3.0.5](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in#-example-tab-) package and followed the instructions given in the documentation and used the exact same code given.

Could someone tell me what I might have missed out on while following the instructions and what I have to do to get this to work.

Comment: Post your trace.

Comment: I'd love to know a fix for this issue, it's not working for me either

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate your client with SHA-1. Do this in a terminal to generate SHA-1

> keytool -exportcert -list -v \ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore

or follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

Then, when you have that you need to copy the SHA-1 to your project settings on Firebase

Comment: Yes I have completed both of these two thing,
I've set my two dependencies to :
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

Comment: Don't use `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1` -> use `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Comment: No this crashes my app, I think I'm not linking my key the right way . Can you tell me where my key needs to be located and how I'm supposed to edit my build.gradle file to point to this key @JanMer

Comment: What key are you talking about?

Comment: @Sebastian keystore signature for your app

Answer (score 0):

The reason for statusCode="Canceled" was because I didn't update my "android/app/build.gradle" file to have it point to the my keystore/key

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("path to key/ key") # .keystore or .jsk file extensions
            storePassword 'password'
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file("path to key/ key") # .keystore or .jsk file extensions
            storePassword 'password'
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }        
    }    

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.applicationName"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }        
    }
}
```